# What is a non-api entry point?

Tags: r, api, entry-point

On Cran packages that use non-api entry points are not allowed. I did not find a suitable definition what a non-api entry point is (in R or in general) and why packages that use them are not allowed on Cran:

(1) What is a non-api entry point?

(2) Why are packages that use non-api entry points not allowed on Cran?

(3) If this should not come up while answering (2): What are possible ramifications of using non-api entry points?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick take:

1. Something not exported in a public header -- and the comments in the R header files generally give you an idea
2. Because R Core reserves the right to change behavior of non-API functions. If nobody uses them ( in public packages), then upon a change in behavior no (public) packages break.
3. You don't get your package onto CRAN, and it may break.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: Can using a package that uses non-api entry points affect the computations in R just because it uses non-api entry points?

Comment: I don;t understand your follow-up question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I am not well acquainted with this. I was wondering whether a package that uses non-api entry points can cause problems in other packages without me knowing about it. (I am using vimcom.plus which is a package that uses non-api entry points.)

Comment: I do not think that can be answered in any generality. "It depends."